# SAP - Understanding HR module structure

Tags: document, documentation-generation, sap-hr

We are in the middle of a huge SAP installation. Everything works fine but I'm dissatisfied with the documentation methodology and style of the consultants/developers.

The documentation is too fine-grained, developers often are lost in details and a bird eye view is terribly missing.

- Is there any tool to generate reports/documentation or crawl infotypes/events/relations?
- Is there any methodology to create (automatic or manual) thumbnail
  documentation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How are the consultants doing the configuration?
If they are using Solution Manager for defining the configuration and providing the configuration rationale there also, then solution manager is able to document. Again this might be too fine grained but my thoughts are that your configuration rationale should actually be sufficiently summarized that you can rely on that for the 10,000ft view.

All that said, the HR structures and infotypes are pretty standardized so I am not sure what exactly it is that you are hoping for that you aren't getting.

As part of the project documentation I would also expect scenarios to be defined (you'll need these for functional testing) - these should articulate the data to be entered, how it is to be entered and how the system will behave and provide feedback. Do you have that ?

Comment: Yes, infotypes are standardized but we are a non-typical organization. And would you please explain it to me: "your configuration rationale should actually be sufficiently summarized"?